# Show a custom field instead of username in the backend author area

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, wp-admin, author

I'm building a new WP site with about 1200 authors(which are actually companies, pulled from my client's existing site), each attached to at least one custom post type.

My problem is the admin(our client) is used to seeing the company name as the 'Author' instead of the username (which is an email address).

Is there a way in the backend to make the normal 'Author' field (ie: in post columns, and in the post editor author metabox) into a custom field (which currently exists in our system) that is the company name(lets call the field 'wp_organization')??

And all this without editing core WP files that could be overwritten during an upgrade(ie: use the functions.php instead?)...

I'd assume its a simple function to call the custom field instead of author, but haven't been able to find it yet...

Answer (score 0):

Like [this](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/plugins/a-guide-to-wordpress-custom-post-types-taxonomies-admin-columns-filters-and-archives/) there are many other tutorials to display custom fields as columns in the WordPress admin. The tutorial will help you to unset the columns you don't want to show and also to show the columns you would like to see. Hope this helps!